# C# Override List<T> Add method to check for list being null

Tags: c#, list, overriding

I am looking to figure out if this is possible / the correct syntax to make it work. I want to do a `null` check on my List when adding a new item at the property level rather than doing a `null` check every time I go to add an item to the list. For example:

```
MyClass someClass = new MyClass()
{
    MyClassID = 1,
    Notes = null
};

//
//

Note newNote = new Note()
{
    NoteID = 1,
    Text = "Test note"
};

someClass.Notes.Add(newNote); // This line will throw an error because 
                              //      someClass.Notes is null
```

I want to solve this by doing something along the lines of the following code. However, I do not know if / what syntax makes this possible.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyClassID { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes
    {
        get; set;

        public void Add(Note note)
        {
            if (this.Notes == null)
                this.Notes = new List<Note>();

            this.Notes.Add(note);
        }
    }
}

public class Note
{
    public int NoteID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

** I know I can do a null check on `someClass.Notes == null` and assign it to `new List<Note>()` before doing the `.Add(newNote)` but I'd like to do it at the property level so I don't have to copy those 2 lines of code every time I need to add a new note.

Comment: Why not just assign a value to `Notes` in the `MyClass` constructor? Also you say _"override List<T> Add method to check for list being null"_ - when `List<T>` is `null`, you don't have a `List<T>`, you have `null`.

Comment: Seems like you'd be working around a bigger problem. Sure it's possible, but should be preventable earlier.

Comment: Initialize the `Notes` property in your `MyClass` constructor and you will save yourself some headaches!

Comment: So is this not possible then? I understand I can initialize in my controller, but I could also do a null check every time I go to insert a note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's introduce *backing field* `private List<Note> m_Notes`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyClassID { get; set; } 

    // Empty list by default
    private List<Note> m_Notes = new List<Note>();

    public List<Note> Notes
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Notes; 
        }
        set // If you really want "set" in the context
        {
            // Assign empty list if value is null
            m_Notes = value ?? new List<Note>();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It's better if you init your list in constructor of `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Notes = new List<Note>();
    }
}
```